# How to run async method using Threadpool

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, async-await, threadpool

I have async method defined in C# class. I want to call this method using multi-threading so that I can run multiple inputs in parallel.

Current code

```
await _handler.Cleanup(id, request);
```

Now I need to run this method for multiple ids in parallel using Threadpool with 10 threads something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(_handler.Cleanup(id, request)));
}
```

I think the syntax is not correct. I want to know how to run async method in Threadpool.
Also is it doable?

Comment: Wouldn't [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) be the correct solution for this? To quote the documentation: "_Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task or Task<TResult> handle for that work._".

Comment: @UweKeim I am new to multithreadin in C3. Can you plz show how the code would look like withasync method?
My application is just console app

Comment: What is the `id` and the `request`? Do you have a `List` of IDs? Is the `request` the same for all of these IDs, or each `id` has its own dedicated `request`? Also what is the version of .NET that you are targeting? Is it .NET 6?

Answer (score 0):

The default scheduler for tasks uses the threadpool, so it's just a matter of starting your tasks and then awaiting them all.

```
var tasks =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 10)
        .Select(i => _handler.Cleanup(id, request))
        .ToArray();
        // .ToArray() forces the tasks to start running now.

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I used this code to test:

```
public static class _handler
{
    internal static async Task Cleanup(int id, string request)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));
    }
}
```

When I ran the code it took 1 second to execute, so it ran all 10 delays simultaneously.